# Preprocessing lung sound data: replication of paper method

Tags: filter-design, audio-processing, mfcc, research

I'm really new to signal processing research. I'm trying to replicate

> Kirill Kochetov and Andrey Filchenkov. 2021. Generative Adversarial Networks for Respiratory Sound Augmentation. In *Proceedings of the 2020 1st International Conference on Control, Robotics and Intelligent System (CCRIS '20)*. Association for Computing Machinery, New York, NY, USA, 106–111. https://doi.org/10.1145/3437802.3437821

and I'm stuck in the preprocessing stage. **Can anyone help me with the steps? Like what should I do after what?**

> To remove heartbeats, the signal components at low frequencies have to be suppressed. We applied the high pass finite impulse response (FIR) filter with cutoff frequency $f_c = 100\,\text{Hz}$ in order to remove sounds caused by heartbeat and extra noises. We used MFCC for data representation. We cut the input data to between $50$ and $2000\,\text{Hz}$ for lower and upper bounds respectively, because almost all anomalies are in this range. Frame length and frame step were chosen to be equal to 0.05 seconds using grid search optimization. Each audio sample from the original database was separated on pieces called frames with length of 0.5 seconds each. Every frame was sliced on 10 non-overlapping frames. Both parameters frame length and frame step are 0.05 seconds. After that we extracted the MFCC set (13 values) from each frame gathered. So, every frame is described by 130 MFCC features. There are four classes in the ICBHI database: normal breathing (no anomalies), breathing with wheezes, breathing with crackles and with both wheezes and crackles.

Comment: Hi :) ! Welcome here! Could you link to the paper you're citing?

Comment: Found the paper! Adding this crucial information to your question.

Comment: That paper explicitly lists the two authors email addresses. Did you ask them for their code? Would be good style to provide their preprocessing code to a fellow researcher! Also, you've in the last few hours asked the same question on two different places on reddit, without reacting to my comment here. What's up with that?

Comment: Hey sorry I haven't been on stackexchange after posting it so i didn't see your comment, there is no reason to be mad. and yes i did reach out to the authors, but didn't get any response

Comment: not mad. Just sad you took the time to post on reddit *after* we asked for clarification here, but didn't find it necessary to check with us  before doing that :(